# $.getJSON Use data argument to modify text on HTML element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am having a bit of trouble with this bit of code. I am to take the values of 4 inputs, pass them to a PHP API using jQuery, compute a password with the PHP API file I have created and return that password as the data argument as a json_encoded. Below you will find the code:

**PHPPasswordGenerator.php**

```
    <?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset: UTF-8;");
$letters = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');
$special = array('!','?',"'",'"','£','$','%','&','/','(',')','=','@','#','§','[',']','{','}');
$minLetters = array();
$maxLetters = array();
$numbers = array();
$specialCharacters = array();
$final = '';
$min = $_REQUEST["typeA"];
$max = $_REQUEST["typeB"];
$num = $_REQUEST["typeC"];
$spec = $_REQUEST["typeD"];

if(isset($min) or isset($max) or isset($num) or isset($special)){
    for($i = 0; $i < $min; $i++){
        array_push($minLetters, $letters[rand(0,count($letters)-1)]);
    }
    for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++){
        array_push($maxLetters, strtoupper($letters[rand(0,count($letters)-1)]));
    }
    for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++){
        array_push($numbers, rand(0,9));
    }
    for($i = 0; $i < $spec; $i++){
        array_push($specialCharacters, $special[rand(0,count($special)-1)]);
    }

    $final .= implode('',$minLetters) . implode('',$maxLetters) . implode('',$numbers) . implode('',$specialCharacters);
    }
    print(json_encode($final));
?>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //Chiamata AJAX sui dati generati dal generatore di Password in PHP
        $("#generator").on("click", function(){
            //Mentre il focus è sull'input, modifica il valore val()
                $.getJSON("passwordgenerator.php",
                          {
                           typeA : $("#typeA").val(),
                           typeB : $("#typeB").val(),
                           typeC : $("#typeC").val(),
                           typeD : $("#typeD").val()
                           },
                           function(data){
                               console.log("Success: " + data);
                               $("#generated").append("<h3></h3>").html(data);
                        }).fail(function(err){console.log(err)});
    });
});
```

**This is part of the body**

```
<form>
    <label for="A">Lettere Minuscole</label><input type="text" name="typeA" id="typeA">
    <label for="B">Lettere Maiuscole</label><input type="text" name="typeB" id="typeB">
    <label for="C">Numeri</label><input type="text" name="typeC" id="typeC">
    <label for="D">Caratteri Speciali</label><input type="text" name="typeD" id="typeD">
    <button id="generator">Generate Password</button>
</form>

<div id="generated"></div>
```

Now, the thing is: whenever I put a number inside the inputs and send it to the PHP file, the `$final` variable is json_encoded and sent back to the javascript file. If I do something like `console.log(data)`, I actually get to see a randomly generated password with the specs I wanted it to be, but then I try to do something like:

`$("#generated").text(data);`

but the data doesn't go inside generated. I also tried to use html(data), but to no use. I did a `console.log(typeof data);` to see that it really was a string, as I wanted, and it actually is.

Comment: try `$("#generated").html(data);`?

Comment: Thank you @Jono20201 but as you can see from what I wrote, it is something I already tried! Tried to use both .html(data) and .text(data) from the jQuery library methods!

Comment: Can you give an example of what the console.log is pushing out?

Comment: The console.log(data) logs into the console something that could look like: 

"Success: xxaabAAAAA12955!"£$%"

and console.log(typeof data) logs to the console "string"

Comment: Is there an example of this on a publicly accessible server that you could link me to? I can't see an obvious reason for this without further debugging.

Comment: makes no sense to use `$.getJSON` or  implode into string to use for json output from server. If you just want string returned use `$.get()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the thing is I had to use val() and $.getJSON() at all costs, because the professor wanted so! The problem: I was using a form. The data passed as expected, but when I tried to append the data to an HTML element, since this event would occur in the same time the default form event would occur, the data would not get appended.

Removing the  element was all it took. I could have also prevented default, yes.

Thank everyone for the nice help! :)

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify(jsondata) to convert JSON into string. If you want to parse data string to JSON than use JSON.parse(string). I didn't get what is your actual question

Comment: The question is about how to attach the data argument to an HTML page! As you can see from my code, I have the data returned from a PHP file and sent back to jQuery as a json_encoded. The problem is, when I try to use the data argument in a .text() or .html() jQuery method, the HTML is never updated to the new values, even though I get the success message in the console!

Now I'm gonna try with your method! Let's hope it works! :)


Edit: No luck even with stringify(data)! Thank you for the help! :)